# Solving for the Function with a Specific Behavior

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

I am trying to determine a strategy to solve for a probability distribution that exhibits the following behavior:

\begin{equation}
 x p(x) = p(-\ln x) 
\end{equation}

My idea was to compare the two Taylor series of $xp(x)$ and $p(-\ln x)$ centered at 0 and 1, respectively and then compare the same power terms.

\begin{equation}
x p(x) = p(0)x + p'(0)x^2+...
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 p(-\ln x) = p(0) - p'(0)(x-1) + \frac{1}{2}\left(p'(0)+p''(0)\right)(x-1)^2+...
\end{equation}

So this provides for order zero the follow, which also needs to equal zero:

\begin{align}
 p(0) + p'(0) + \frac{1}{2}\left(p'(0)+p''(0)\right) -\frac{1}{6}\left(2p'(0)+3p''(0)+p'''(0)\right)+...= 0\\
\end{align}

This gets messy quickly.

I can pursue this approach, but I wonder if there is a technique to this that I am unaware of.

Comment: I probably misunderstand but what is the goal ?

Comment: Hi @ClaudeLeibovici - Bascially I am trying to find a probability distribution that remains invariant under a specific transformation. If you simplify the transformation, you get the first equality. I am trying to now find a way to handle the p(-ln x) term as I have not seen a good way to handle these in any probability or statistics literature.

Comment: Your functional equation is equivalent to $p(u)=e^{-u}p(e^{-u})$ which is a little more handy.

Comment: I have a problem with the support of $p$. We clearly must have $x>0$ for your relationship to hold (because $p(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$, but if $x>1$, we deal for example if we take $x=e$ with a $p(-1)$...

Comment: Is $p(x)$ supposed to be the density, or something else?

Comment: Your issue is interesting, and I would be happy to give it an answer, but please answer first our questions.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for these insights! I am interested in the probability distribution (or distributions) that meet this criterion.